# Providing file share access to iPads

Tags: network-share, ipad

I am working in a Linux environment that is considering adding iPads (vs MS tablets) for the executives.  One important requirement is access to files on the corporate server.

The server runs linux, so we already have SMB shares, and can add any other Linux compatible shares.  But can an iPad access those shares?  Any additional tools/software needed?  Can standard Apple apps open files from a network share?

Comment: I don't think iPads have file browsers at all. You could use cloud services like OneDrive and DropBox to move files to/from an iPad but if you want SMB you should look again at the Surface line. This from a die hard Apple fan.